# Occasional distorted display when scrolling text using JScrollPane

Tags: java, text, jscrollpane, jeditorpane, distortion

I have an application that displays text in a JEditorPane contained within a JScrollPane.   60 users have this application.    Occasionally on one user's machine, when she scrolls the text the display suddenly becomes distorted.   Part of the the text appears the way it did before the scroll and part of it appears the way it did after the scroll.   The effect is like it would be if someone pulled some of the pixels down the screen and left others in tact.   I don't believe this is a software problem because it only happens in one screen but I would like to help this poor user out.   Any ideas?

Comment: It really sounds like a hardware issue on that computer. Is it a different model than the others ? Does the problem happen with other things, or just in this EditorPane ?

Comment: Just with the EditorPane

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you JDK version matched with this bug description https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5087395